# Track number of users online using Codeigniter (v2)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, frameworks, tracking

I am using Codeigniter 2 and would like to track the number of current users on a site into the database. I know this can be achieved using the built-in session class but I am unsure of what I am doing wrong - I've created the ci_sessions table in MySQL and set the following in the config - do I need to make any other adjustments to auto record sessions into the database when someone visits the site?

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think this thread could help you http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/74648/

Comment: I understand this is not what you asked but you should checkout Google Analytic's Real Time Beta.  Works great, and doesn't add to your overhead.

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your current session setup?

Comment: Aha.. didnt think about GA Real Time - that sounds ideal :)

Comment: @Colin - it doesnt seem to write to the DB? Or do I need to do some custom controller/logic for this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**model**

```
class online_users_mod extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  //getting all session data
  function get_all_session_data(){
    $query=$this->db->select('user_data')->get('ci_sessions');
    return $query;
  }
}
```

**controller**

```
class online_users_lib extends CI_Controller{
  //put your code here

/**
 * CodeIgniter global
 *
 * @var string
 **/
protected $ci;

public function __construct() {
  $this->ci =& get_instance();
  $this->ci->load->model('online_users_mod');
}

//getting all online session data

function get_all_session_data(){
  $query=$this->ci->online_users_mod->get_all_session_data();
  $user = array();

    /* array to store the user data we fetch */
    $j=0;$k=0;
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $udata = unserialize($row->user_data);

        /* put data in array using username as key */

        if(isset($udata['yourlogin_data'])) 
        {
            if($udata['yourlogin_data']['User_cat']==2)
            {
                $user[$j]['yourlogin_data'] = $udata['yourlogin_data'];
                $j++;
            }

        }
    }
    return $user ;
 }
}
```